# SQLServerDriver maven dependency causes errors

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jdbc, pom.xml

To fix the  `org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]` error i added this dependency to my pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
```

which is the open code dependency for a SQLServer connection driver, but when i put it, an error my pom.xml appears:

```
Missing artifact org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:2.8.1
```

UPDATED:

If i run the app anyway, the log console shows this trace:

```
15:42:28,432 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."vp301b-ear.ear/vp301b.war#unidadPersistencia": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."vp301b-ear.ear/vp301b.war#unidadPersistencia": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoadingException
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoadingException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1404)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ClassLoadingException from [Module "deployment.vp301b-ear.ear.vp301b.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 14 more
```

When i try to compile it using `mvn comile`, this is the result:

```
 Failed to execute goal on project vp301b-war: Could not resolve dependencies for project es.xunta.amtega.vp301b:vp301b-war:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:2.8.1 in http://nexus.xunta.local/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of amtega has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :vp301b-war
```

Comment: First no error screenshot and it would be better to have the error message as text instead. Furthermore which head do you mean? Of the jackson-mapper-asl:jar ? Also a full log output would helpful ?...

Comment: @khmarbaise question updated.

Comment: This is the issue: `org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:2.8.1 in http://nexus.xunta.local/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of amtega has elaps`...The real issue is that the version given does not exist in central: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.codehaus.jackson%20AND%20a:jackson-mapper-asl&core=gav  I don't know why you are trying to require this dependency?...

Comment: @khmarbaise i see... then the most appropiate question would be, What dependency for sqlserver connection driver i need to connect my app with the database.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted by khmarbaise, the problem is that `jackson-mapper-asl-2.8.1.jar` is not available in your repository.  However I see that `mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre7.jar` has a transitive dependency on version 1.9.2, not 2.8.1, of jackson-mapper-asl so I guess that something you stated is wrong (maybe you were making many attempts).  I suggest to try with version **6.4.0.jre7** of the JDBC driver because it doesn't depends on jackson-mapper-asl at all and is the latest jre7-based version available.

Also note that a JDBC driver should not be included in the classpath of your war but in the classpath of the application server (I'm assuming that your web-app accesses the DB in the proper way, that is through a server-provided connection pool, not through `DriverManager`); this means that the driver should not be a compile-scope dependency in your POM.

Comment: The driver works, thank you!,I already have the driver in the server classpath,and i connected succesfully to my database. But once i added the persistence.xml, i needed to solve many bugs, and this was one of these. Without the driver in my pom, it lauchs  "  org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]"